# C# Can't access class instance from different method than it was instantiated in

Tags: c#

The problem I have may be a fairly obvious one but im new to c# and coding in general. I have looked around online but I couldn't find anything that could help me. This is a demo code I prepared for the situation im in.

```
class Program
{
    class Person                             //The class
    {
        public string jobTitle = "Cashier";    

        public void Greet()                    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, im bob.");
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)   //Method it was instantiated in
    {
        Person Bob = new Person();
        Bob.Greet();

    }

    public static void OtherMethod()      //Method I want to access it in
    {
        Bob.Greet();
        Console.WriteLine(Bob.jobTitle);  //"'Bob' does not exist in the current context"
    }
}
```

This is a serious problem for me because im working on something that has alot of classes and I am forced to use temp variables to transfer the class data from Main() into the parameters of another method. Also on a side note, none of the data im trying to access is static. I can access it in Main().

I just want to know if im missing something here?

Comment: `Bob` is a variable declared in `Main`.

Comment: Re-read your study materials about variable scope and visibility.

Comment: If you didn't find anything about scope, here's an article that goes into the issue: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/ . Basically, Bob is only visible to the method it was declared in.

Answer (score 3):

there is no meaning of having class inside class (`Person` class in `Program` class)

if you need to access `Bob` within same class check the code below

```
public class Person                            
{
    public string jobTitle = "Cashier";    

    public void Greet()                
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, im bob.");
    }
}

public static class Program
{
    private Person _bob;
    public static void Main(string[] args)   
    {
        _bob = new Person();
        _bob.Greet();
        OtherMethod();

    }

    public static void OtherMethod()      
    {
        _bob.Greet();
        Console.WriteLine(_bob.jobTitle);  
    }
}
```

Comment: "there is no meaning of having class inside class" - You can indeed have classes within other classes; these are called [nested types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types). Or are you saying that it doesn't make sense to use nested types in this case specifically?

Comment: for this case it doesn't have meaning. But in general, nested classes are rarely used.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem I have may be a fairly obvious one but I'm new to c# and coding in general.

It is an obvious problem, but it is also a problem common to beginners; we were all beginners once!

> I have looked around online but I couldn't find anything that could help me.

You would likely benefit from a more focussed course of study than just browsing the internet and hoping for the best. Consider investing in a good beginner book.

> I am forced to use temp variables to transfer the class data from Main() into the parameters of another method

**That is normal and good when not taken to extremes**.  When taken to extremes, the pattern you are describing is called "tramp data", because you end up "tramping around" data from method to method.

Programmers who try too hard to avoid tramp data end up in a bad pattern at the other end of the spectrum: *relying on global state*.

There is no one magic way that is "always right". However it is generally accepted that *a method's actions and return values should depend mostly on their arguments*; remember that "this" is logically an argument.

Let's look at your code and **get you out of bad habits while you are still a beginner**.

```
class Program
{
    class Person                    
    {
```

Nested classes are legal in C# but are most often used for advanced scenarios where types are implementation details of other types.  **Break this up into two non-nested classes**.

```
class Person                    
{ ... }

class Program
{ ... }
```

Let's look at Person:

```
class Person //The class
```

Do not leave comments that explain what is obvious.  `class Person` is obviously a class; you don't have to say it again.  My guideline is to write code *so clearly* that it does not need a comment explaining *what it does*.  Use comments to explain *why code has to exist*.

```
{
    public string jobTitle = "Cashier";
```

Public fields are a bad programming practice in C#.  Use a public property, and `CaseItLikeThis`. In C# 7, that's very concise:

```
    public string JobTitle => "Cashier";
```

In earlier versions of C# you'd say

```
    public string JobTitle { get { return "Cashier"; } }
```

Moving on:

```
    public void Greet()                    
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, im bob.");
    }
}
```

**Good programmers pay close attention to even the smallest details.**

```
        Console.WriteLine("Hi, I'm Bob.");
```

All right, that does it for `Person`.

Your problem in `Program` that you are actually asking about is that `OtherMethod` can't see local variable `Bob` -- which should be renamed `bob`; local variables are `casedLikeThis`.

There are three ways you'd typically solve that.

1. Pass `bob` as an argument; make `OtherMethod` take a `Person` as a formal parameter.
2. Make `bob` a private static field. Assign the field in `Main`, and use it from `OtherMethod`.
3. Make `bob` a private instance field. Create a `new Program()`, assign the `bob` field, and make `OtherMethod` an *instance* method.  You can then access `this.bob` from `OtherMethod`.

My advice to you is: **write the program all three ways**.  This will be good practice.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is a matter of scope and context. It's common to have these problems at first starting with programming.

Pointing out why you cannot access Bob in the second method:

```
class Program
{
    class Person                             //The class
    {
        public string jobTitle = "Cashier";    

        public void Greet()                    
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi, im bob.");
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)   //Method it was instantiated in
    { 
        // Bob is instantiated local to the main method
        Person Bob = new Person();
        Bob.Greet();
        //You didn't call OtherMethod() here
    }

    public static void OtherMethod()      //Method I want to access it in
    {
        // Since Bob was not passed in as a parameter or accessible via a global var, here you dont have access to it.  access it
        Bob.Greet();
        Console.WriteLine(Bob.jobTitle);  //"'Bob' does not exist in the current context"
    }
}
```

Here, building on your example, a version that works:

```
class Program
    {
         static Person GlobalBob;  // must be static because we are instantiating it inside a static method

        class Person
        {
            public string jobTitle = "Cashier";

            public void Greet()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hi, im bob.");
            }
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)   //Method it was instantiated in
        {
            GlobalBob = new Person();
            GlobalBob.Greet();
            OtherMethod();                       //Call your OtherMethod here otherwise it's not gonna be executed

        }

        public static void OtherMethod()      //Method I want to access it in
        {
            GlobalBob.Greet();
            Console.WriteLine(GlobalBob.jobTitle);  //Here we have access to GlobalBob 
            Console.ReadLine(); //Wait for you to press a key so you can read the output !
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!